# how to redirect https\\:www to non www while it says connection is not private

Tags: asp.net, url, https, redirect

I have read lots of articles and none of them works for my problem 
I implement a web project with Asp.net and I put SSL certificate on my website. everything works fine but when I type `https://www.forexample.com` it confronts an error says This connection is not private but if I type `https://forexample.com` then it works completely fine. I do not know how should I fix it.

here is my rules in web.config to redirect

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://forexample.com/{R:1}"></action>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^forexample\.com$" negate="true"></add>
      </conditions>
    </rule>


     <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="(.*)" /> 
<conditions> 
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule>


  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

which it is in system.webServer .
I think I should find a way to redirect https\:www to non www
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to accept the request to `https://www` in order to perform a redirect.  This means you need a certificate that can handle that subdomain.  The common solution is to get a wildcard certificate so you could handle `*.yourdomain.com`.  This would cover `www` and any other subdomains you wish to use in the future.

Comment: you mean I should ask another request from my host and domain provider company? and you mean there is no way to redirect https www to https non www?

Comment: If you want to redirect anything you first have to be able to handle that initial request.  Without a valid certificate on the first request you can't handle it (redirect or not).  A wild card certificate would take care of this.

Comment: so I should ask a wild card certificate from my host and domain provider? thank you very much for your care

Comment: Yes, you'll need either a wild card certificate or a certificate specifically for `www`.

Comment: I have one certificate right now, you mean I should buy two certificate one for with www and one with no www? if so why should I do this? if I could redirect just one to another like https non www to www it would be solved. why I need another certificate?

Comment: If you already have a wild card cert then you're all set.  Get it setup on all domains you want to accept requests on.

Comment: I have asked them and they told me my certificate is a kind of wild card which it can be used on subdomains and addon domains. so what should I do right now?